# Cannot Get Blob Container Reference

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get a container reference using an instance of the CloudBlobClient. In the emulator, everything works properly but if I deploy to azure, the second line of:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
blobClient.GetContainerReference("drives").CreateIfNotExist();
```

fails with an IOException and says "The specified registry key does not exist". What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured out what was going wrong. THe IOException is commonly generated by the HTTPWebRequest Class which made me think that since the .Net libraries are only API wrappers, some erroneous calls were being made. I was using the Cloud Drive so I had a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient which is API version 1.7 and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage which is version 2.0. The two of these were interfering with each other. Because I needed to keep Cloud Drive capabilities, I removed the Storage Class and everything worked.